# Return a string instead of a view when unauthorized asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.net identity, it allows me to configure to return a view if unauthorized, but now I want to return string instead, so what i need to do ?

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {                   
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            });
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have anything to do with returning a `View` if unauthorized.

Comment: @Dai As i know, if unauthorized will return view set at LoginPath.

Comment: Why you want string instead of login page? Can you explain the use case_

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: because i dont use MVC, i using Webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creates a controller that will return string and place it in `LoginPath`